# Json passing dates as data to web service

Tags: ajax, json, web-services

net and json. I know am stuck at an easy problem but whatever I do its still there. Can you guys help me please. Am pasting my code here.

```
var req = jQuery.ajax({
type: "POST",
contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
url: "WebService1.asmx/GridJson2",
data: { Date1: $('#start').text() , Date2: $('#end').text() },
accepts: 'application/json',
dataType: 'json',
success: function (data) {
        var jsonData = data;
        var LocalData = jQuery.parseJSON(data.d);
        buildJqgrid(LocalData);
    }
})
```

And here are my textboxes

```
Start Date:  <input type="text" id="start" /> <br />        
End Date :   <input type="text" id="end" /> <br />
```

My Text boxes are getting dates as input. Now I want to send these values to web service as parameters. My problem is with the `data` field of Json. Have a look please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use date format in your json like this '12-31-2000'.

Comment: You mean   data: { Date1: $('#start').text() , Date2: $('#end').text() }, has no problem ?

Comment: try {"Date1":"12-31-2000"}

Comment: Kostas its a custom filter so the user enters the date using date picker and then that date is to be sent. am getting that date as "#start".text() .

Comment: I think you can you translate the value you get from the control. Try to parse the value you get fro mthe users to the format you want.

Comment: Thank you kostas but I soled the problem.
data: "{'date1': '" + $('#start').val() + "', 'date2': '" + $('#end').val() + "' }",  is the correct code